# Mouse Over on item

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

im trying to make a mouse over on items to show me a message, i did follow one tutorial and did change according to what i want the final goal to be, but im stuck in one thing, so im making it a top down, and i want the message to show the string from the items im mouse over, and right now its doing the things my char is looking at and not the mouse over. what am i doing wrong?I think my mistake is in the Sphere Trace By Channel, but not sure and tryed some alternatives but cant figure it out[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your blueprint code, it looks like you're getting the player's location and then checking if there's anything in front of the player; if there is, you're printing the string from the `Mouse Over` function.

I suggest that you use the `Get Hit Result Under Cursor for Objects` instead of using the `Sphere Trace` https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Game/Player/GetHitResultUnderCursorforObject-/

You should use that in your Character blueprint. Here's a cool video explaining how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMjnbnQd1dI; it also explains the difference between checking the cursor collision through a channel or objects.